# Will multithreaded reading lead to low performance?

Tags: multithreading, sqlite

I write my code to **select** concurrent in 3 threads with one-thread-one-connection; I found that it is slower than in 1 thread;

Here are my test data:
It's a table(index uint32) with 100000 items;

when I **select** 100000 items(all items) in 3 threads:

```
0: 1443185531.782627, info: <NSThread: 0x13f99ac40>{number = 4, name = (null)} read ready
1: 1443185531.782634, cost 0.000007, info: <NSThread: 0x13f99ac40>{number = 4, name = (null)} read start
2: 1443185533.365550, cost 1.582916, info: <NSThread: 0x13f99ac40>{number = 4, name = (null)} read end

0: 1443185531.772624, info: <NSThread: 0x13f871e60>{number = 2, name = (null)} read ready
1: 1443185531.782659, cost 0.010035, info: <NSThread: 0x13f871e60>{number = 2, name = (null)} read start
2: 1443185533.372972, cost 1.590313, info: <NSThread: 0x13f871e60>{number = 2, name = (null)} read end

0: 1443185531.773191, info: <NSThread: 0x13f99a6a0>{number = 3, name = (null)} read ready
1: 1443185531.782636, cost 0.009445, info: <NSThread: 0x13f99a6a0>{number = 3, name = (null)} read start
2: 1443185533.393716, cost 1.611080, info: <NSThread: 0x13f99a6a0>{number = 3, name = (null)} read end
```

You can see it costs 1.5s average.
But when I change to **select** 100000 items(all items) in 1 thread:

```
0: 1443185738.427020, info: <NSThread: 0x14d970990>{number = 2, name = (null)} read ready
1: 1443185738.427106, cost 0.000086, info: <NSThread: 0x14d970990>{number = 2, name = (null)} read start
2: 1443185739.020410, cost 0.593304, info: <NSThread: 0x14d970990>{number = 2, name = (null)} read end
```

The cost comes to 0.5s.

So I confuse that will multithread reading slow down the performance of sqlite3.

As I know, reading use the shared-mutex, which can be shared in multithread. Lower performance should not be happened.

Is anyone can solve my confusing?

---

Additional:
sqlite3 is in WAL, SQLITE_CONFIG_MULTITHREAD mode, without any manually mutex.

---

Additional:
I run my code in 3 threads in this way.

```
//objc code
dispatch_async(name1, ^{
    select * in conn1
}
dispatch_async(name2, ^{
    select * in conn2
}
dispatch_async(name3, ^{
    select * in conn3
}
```

Comment: Instead of using the same connection in each thread (which the threads can't use at the same time), create one connection for each thread.

Comment: I understand every thread has its own handle to sqlite (one-thread-one-handle). You are using threads in the wrong way. You asked your software to do the same work 3 times and so it did (taking more time).

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo I do use its own connection in every thread. ( one-thread-one-connection written)

Comment: @user430051 I don't really understand. What did I wrong using threads? Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

This is not suprising. All your threads use shared connection to database, and are synchronized on it. As a result, only one thread is really executed at a given moment. Add context-switching and you see why performance degrades.

If you give every thread it's own connection, there will be no synchronization within your thread, you should see improved performance.

Comment: I do use its own connection in every thread. ( one-thread-one-connection written)

Answer (score 0):

Ill try to answer with an example. It really doesn't matter for the purpose of this scenario how clients talk with the server or context switching, virtualization, multiple cores and so forth (but notice that all that come into account when you're designing a system in a spec):

You have a server with N clients. Clients come and go, and have distinct requests. Some clients make quick, small and frequent requests. Others make less requests that take longer to return.

If you have a single process/thread, you can only process one request for one client at a time - you have a stack of clients, each with a stack of requests.

Now, assuming you want to use threads to parallelize your workload, you can have (one of many possibilities) one thread for each client. You'll have a stack of threads (each one represents a client). Each thread will have then a stack of that client request's. The operating system will split (context switch) processing time between those multiple tasks and you'll have a batter overall response.

Your current approach does not explore the use of parallel processing - you're just asking the threads to do the same work.

Even so, that alone is not enough reason for your code to linearly increase the amount of time. I suspect that somewhere, you may be sharing the same resource - that will be the bottleneck.

You can google a lot of material for when to use threads. One of the best resources I've found to understand threads was the [C10k problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C10k_problem). You can find a archived version of the paper [here](http://www.webcitation.org/6ICibHuyd).